# Use functions inside of page-object commands in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

Ignore the placement of the `selectUser` function. I'm still trying to play around with it. How can I use functions inside of the page-object `commands`? Before that function was repeated 5 times inside each command function, but for cleanliness, that obviously needed to be changed, I just can't figure out how.

Page-object snippet:

```
var selectUser = function(userName, password) {
  return this.waitForElementVisible('@usernameField')
    .setValue('@usernameField', userName)
    .setValue('@passwordField', password)
    .click('@signOnButton')
    .waitForElementVisible('@eventTaskManager');
};

module.exports = {
  elements: {
    usernameField: '#UserName',
    passwordField: '#Password',
    signOnButton: 'input[value="Sign On"]',
    cancelButton: 'a[href$="/cancel"]',
    errorMessage: '.icon-warning',
    eventTaskManager: '.concierge'
  },

  commands: [{
    signInAsUniregisteredUser: function() {
      selectUser(unregisteredUserName, unregisteredUserPass);
    },

    signInAsRegisteredUser: function() {
      selectUser(registeredUserName, prodRegisteredPass);
    },

    signInAsUnregisteredUser_Regression: function() {
      selectUser(unregisteredUserName, unregisteredUserPass);
    },

    signInAsRegisteredUser_Regression: function() {
      selectUser(registeredUserName, prodRegisteredPass);
    },

    signInAsRegisteredUser_Production: function() {
      selectUser(prodRegisteredUser, prodRegisteredPass);
    }
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First at all, for login feature, there are only 2 assertions which are login "ok" or login "fail" (unregistered,wrong credentials,missing username,...), so you only need this for page object.

```
    var pageCommands = {
    tryToLogin: function(userName, password) {
        return this.waitForElementVisible('@usernameField')
            .setValue('@usernameField', userName)
            .setValue('@passwordField', password)
            .click('@signOnButton');
    },
    assertLoginSuccesfully: function() {
        return this.waitForElementVisible('@eventTaskManager'); // login pass    
    },
    assertLoginUnSuccesfully: function() {
        return this.waitForElementVisible('@errorMessage'); // login fail 
    }
};

module.exports = {
    elements: {
        usernameField: '#UserName',
        passwordField: '#Password',
        signOnButton: 'input[value="Sign On"]',
        cancelButton: 'a[href$="/cancel"]',
        errorMessage: '.icon-warning',
        eventTaskManager: '.concierge'
    },

    commands: [pageCommands],
};
```

And in your test cases :

```
const loginPage = browser.page.login();
const dataForTest = require('./data.json');
const credentials = { 
   username : dataForTest.username , 
   password : dataForTest.password
};

login.tryToLogin(credentials.username,credentials.password)
     .assertLoginSuccesfully() // if data from dataForTest is correct
```

This practice will keep you stay away of hard values by storing every thing in data.json (or anything you want).

Comment: Excellent thank you. But in general, how would you use functions inside of commands? Hypothetically, lets keep the values hard coded. Converting a protractor script to nightwatch and there are more functions than just the login example.

Comment: this method does not work for me. I get TypeError - page is not a function. @inShaneity This code looks wrong: login.tryToLogin should maybe say loginPage.tryToLogin